# Declaring UI Objects

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, uilabel

Curiosity Question: 
I just was wondering if there is a real different between the following:

```
let champNameLabel: UILabel!
champNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake( 0, 0,  cellSize(champsPerRow),  textHeight))
champNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(textCenterX, textCenterY)
champNameLabel.textAlignment = .Center
champNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
champNameLabel.font = champNameLabel.font.fontWithSize(fontSize)
contentView.addSubview(champNameLabel)
```

And,

```
let champNameLabel = UILabel()
champNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0,  cellSize(champsPerRow),  textHeight)
champNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(textCenterX, textCenterY)
champNameLabel.textAlignment = .Center
champNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
champNameLabel.font = champNameLabel.font.fontWithSize(fontSize)
contentView.addSubview(champNameLabel)
```

I have seen it both ways around the web in tutorials and wanted to know if one way was better or not. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: They invoke different constructors. In this case, there's no difference. It could matter in some cases, though, depending on the operation of the constructor vs setting properties.

Comment: Okay cool. I had a feeling it would come down to something small like that but figured if there was a "better way" (best practices) I would get in the habit of doing it that way.

Comment: As for best practices: `let` is used for constants. At declaration time, if you know the value you want to assign, assign it (your second example). If you don't know the value you want to assign at declaration time but are sure you'll only ever assign it once, just set the type as you've done in the first example. If you might want to assign a different value later, use `var` instead.